# Correct way to link to a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code organized in some (several) files. For the sake of organization of folders and the `CMakeLists.txt`, a pythonlibs folder is created during the build process, and some links to python files are created to libraries in the `/build/src/XXXX/` folder.

In the python file, I add to the python path:

```
  sys.path.insert(1,'/opt/hpc/softwares/erfe/erfe/build/pythonlibs')
  import libmsym as msym
```

When I run the main python file, there is this one library lybmsym that fails with:

```
    import libmsym as msym
  File "/opt/hpc/softwares/erfe/erfe/build/pythonlibs/libmsym.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import _libmsym_install_location, export
  ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I created a link using cmake, but I believe it does use the ln command (tried both hard and symbolic). Is there a way to prevent this behavior without changing the library itself, just another way to create this link?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if libmsyms.py is a copy and not a link?

Comment: It doesn`t work also